# Working with a MariaDB view that generates a lot of calculated statistics - How to move to a calculated table?

Tags: mysql, date, join, mariadb, query-performance

I currently have a MariaDB database that gets populated every day with different products (around 800) and also gets the price updates for these products.

I've created a view on top of the prices/products table that generates statistics such as the avg, mean and mode for the last 7, 15 and 30 days, and calculates the difference from today's price to the averages of 7, 15 and 30 days.

The problem is that whenever I run this view it takes almost 50 seconds to generate the data. I saw some comments about switching over to a calculated table, in which the calculations would be updated when new data is entered into the table, however I'm quite skeptical in doing that, as I'm inserting around 1000 price points at one specific time of the day that will impact all the calculations on the table. Is a calculated table something that updates only the rows that were updated, or it would recalculate everything? I'm worried about the overhead this might cause (memory is not an issue with the server).

I've pasted the products and prices tables and the view to DBFiddle, here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4cf594a85f950bed34f64d800601baa9

Calculations can be seen for product code `22141`

Just to give an idea these are some of the calculations done by the view (available on the fiddle as well):

```
        ROUND((((SELECT preconormal
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 9 HOUR) / (SELECT AVG(preconormal)
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) - 1) * 100), 2) as dif_7_dias,
        ROUND((((SELECT preconormal
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 9 HOUR) / (SELECT AVG(preconormal)
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY) - 1) * 100), 2) as dif_15_dias,
        ROUND((((SELECT preconormal
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 9 HOUR) / (SELECT AVG(preconormal)
        FROM precos
        WHERE codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
            AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY) - 1) * 100), 2) as dif_30_dias
```

If switching to a calculated table, is there an optimal way to do this?

Comment: There are no indexe on your tables

Comment: They do in real life, as well as the codigowine is a FK from products in the price table and PK on products. Sorry for not adding that.

Comment: Ok. Later i will optimize your query,  but i cant test the perforace with the small data. Then you can test iton your system

Comment: How many prices per product per day?  If many, the build and maintain a summary table with one row per product per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query:  Try refactoring it to eliminate as many dependent subqueries as possible, and instead JOINing to subqueries. Eliminating those dependent subqueries will make a *vast* performance difference.

Figuring the mode is an application of finding the detail record for an extreme value in a dataset.  If you use this as a subquery

```
    WITH freq AS (
            SELECT COUNT(*) freq,
                   ROUND(preconormal, 2) preconormal,
                   codigowine
              FROM precos
              WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
              GROUP BY  ROUND(preconormal, 2), codigowine
        ),
        most AS (
           SELECT MAX(freq) freq,
                  codigowine
             FROM freq
            GROUP BY codigowine
       ),
       mode AS (
         SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(preconormal ORDER BY preconormal DESC) modeps,
                freq.codigowine
           FROM freq
           JOIN most ON freq.freq = most.freq
          GROUP BY freq.codigowine
       )
       SELECT * FROM mode
```

You can find the most frequent price for each item.  The first CTE, `freq`, gets the prices and their frequencies.

The second CTE, `most`, finds the frequency of the most frequent price (or prices).

The third CTE, `mode`, extracts the most frequent prices from `freq` using a JOIN.  It also uses GROUP_CONCAT() because it's possible to have more than one mode--most frequent price.

For your stats you can do this:

```
WITH s7 AS (
  SELECT ROUND(MIN(preconormal), 2) minp,
         ROUND(AVG(preconormal), 2) meanp,
         ROUND(MAX(preconormal), 2) maxp,
         codigowine
    FROM precos
   WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   GROUP BY codigowine
),
s15 AS (
  SELECT ROUND(MIN(preconormal), 2) minp,
         ROUND(AVG(preconormal), 2) meanp,
         ROUND(MAX(preconormal), 2) maxp,
         codigowine
    FROM precos
   WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY
   GROUP BY codigowine
),
s30 AS (
  SELECT ROUND(MIN(preconormal), 2) minp,
         ROUND(AVG(preconormal), 2) meanp,
         ROUND(MAX(preconormal), 2) maxp,
         codigowine
    FROM precos
   WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
   GROUP BY codigowine
),
m7 AS (
   WITH freq AS (
         SELECT COUNT(*) freq,
                ROUND(preconormal, 2) preconormal,
                codigowine
           FROM precos
           WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
           GROUP BY  ROUND(preconormal, 2), codigowine
     ),
     most AS (
        SELECT MAX(freq) freq,
               codigowine
          FROM freq
         GROUP BY codigowine
    ),
    mode AS (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(preconormal ORDER BY preconormal DESC) modeps,
             freq.codigowine
        FROM freq
        JOIN most ON freq.freq = most.freq
       GROUP BY freq.codigowine
    )
    SELECT * FROM mode
)
SELECT v.codigowine, v.nomevinho, DATE(timestamp) AS data_adc,
       s7.minp min_7_dias, s7.maxp max_7_dias,  s7.meanp media_7_dias, m7.modeps moda_7_dias,
       s15.minp min_15_dias, s15.maxp max_15_dias,  s15.meanp media_15_dias, 
       s30.minp min_30_dias, s30.maxp max_30_dias,  s30.meanp media_30_dias
  FROM vinhos v
  LEFT JOIN s7 ON v.codigowine = s7.codigowine
  LEFT JOIN m7 ON v.codigowine = m7.codigowine
  LEFT JOIN s15 ON v.codigowine = s15.codigowine
  LEFT JOIN s30 ON v.codigowine = s30.codigowine
```

I'll leave it to you to do the modes for 15 and 30 days.

This is quite the query. You better hope the next guy to work on it doesn't curse your name. :-)

Comment: We probably want outer joins to s7, s15, for the cases where there are no rows for a particular codigowine.   We could also use conditional aggregation pattern to return the 7 day, 15 day and 30 day stats in a single CTE.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite a lesson! I learned more by reading your (and others) answers than I did in a couple of semesters in class.

Comment: @O. Jones just wanted to say that I went down from 58 seconds to 0.0421 seconds with all the calculations implemented, including all the modes and the average drops/increases for each combination of days. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, thanks for following up with the performance increase. It's excellent!  And, correlated subqueries ....not so good....

Answer (score 2):

A "calculated table" isn't a MySQL / MariaDB feature. So I guess you mean another table derived from your raw data, that you use when you need those statistics.

You say the table is "populated every day...". Do you mean it's reloaded from scratch, or do you mean 800 more rows are added?  By "every day" do you mean at a particular time of day, or ongoing throughout the day.

Do you always have to select all rows from your view, or can you sometimes do `SELECT columns FROM view WHERE something = 'constant';`' This matters because optimization techniques differ between the all-rows case and the few-rows case.

How can you handle this problem efficiently?

1. You could work to optimize the query used to define your view, making it faster. That is very likely a good approach.
2. MariaDB has a type of column known as a Persistent Computed Column. These are computed when rows are INSERTED or UPDATED. Then they are available for quick reference. But they have limitations; they cannot be defined with subqueries.
3. You could define an EVENT (a scheduled SQL job) to do the following.

   - Create a new, empty, "calculated" table with a name like `tbl_new`.
   - Use your (slow) view to insert the rows it needs.
   - Roll over your tables, so the new one replaces the current one and you keep a couple of older ones. This will give you a brief window where `tbl` doesn't exist.

     - DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_old_2;
     - RENAME TABLE tbl_old TO tbl_old_2, tbl TO tbl_old, tbl_new TO tbl;

Comment: When I mean it’s populated every day I mean that 800 rows are added (I only add products that didn’t exist previously). By every day I men at 9AM a Python job kicks in and paginates through an API, checks if the products do not exist and add them, as well as price points for all products on that day.

I can do a SELECT column FROM view, but generally on the backend, I do want to look for all columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a whole boatload of correlated subqueries, crying out for appropriate indexing.

For a reasonable number of rows being returned by the query, the correlated subqueries can give reasonable performance. But if the outer query is returning thousands of rows, that will be thousands of executions of the subqueries.

I would tend to avoid running multiple SELECT against the same table, to get the last 7 days, the last 15 days, the last 30 days, and then repeating that to get AVG, repeating that to get MAX, and again to get MIN.

Instead, I would tend towards using conditional aggregation, to get all of the stats AVG, MAX, MIN, for all of the time periods 30 days, 15 days, and 7 days, in a single pass through the table.

---

... pause to note that views can be a problematic for performance; predicates from the outer query may not get pushed into the view query.  We're not seeing what the whole view definition is doing, but I suspect we may be materializing a large set.

---

Consider a query like this:

```
SELECT ...
     , ROUND( ( n.mal / a.avg_07_day - 1)*100 ,2)     AS dif_7_dias
     , ROUND( ( n.mal / a.avg_15_day - 1)*100 ,2)     AS dif_15_dias
     , ROUND( ( n.mal / a.avg_30_day - 1)*100 ,2)     AS dif_30_dias
     , ...
  FROM vinhos
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT h.codigowine
              , AVG(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS avg_30_day
              , MAX(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS max_30_day
              , MIN(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS min_30_day
              , AVG(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -15 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS avg_15_day 
              , MAX(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -15 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS max_15_day 
              , MIN(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -15 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS min_15_day 
              , AVG(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL  -7 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS avg_07_day
              , MAX(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL  -7 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS max_07_day
              , MIN(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL  -7 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS min_07_day
           FROM precos h
          GROUP
             BY h.codigowine
         HAVING h.codigowine IS NOT NULL
       ) a
    ON a.codigowine = vinhos.codigowine

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT s.codigowine
              , MAX(s.precnormal) AS mal
              , MIN(s.precnormal) AS mil
           FROM precos s
          WHERE s.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 9 HOUR
          GROUP 
             BY s.codigowine
         HAVING s.codigowine IS NOT NULL
       ) n
    ON n.codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
```

Consider the inline view query `a`.

Note that we can run that SELECT separately, and get a resultset returned, like we would return a result from a table.  We expect this to do a *single* pass through the referenced table. There may be some predicates (conditions in the WHERE clause) that will filter our row, or enable us to make better use of an index. As currently written, the query could make use of an index with leading column of `codigowine` to avoid a (potentially expensive) "Using filesort" operation to satisfy the `GROUP BY`.

---

I'm a bit confused by the queries the - INTERVAL 9 HOUR. It looks to me like those subqueries could potentially return more than one row. There's no LIMIT clause (and no ORDER BY)... but it looks like we are expecting a single value (scalar), given the division operation.

Without an understanding of what we're trying to achieve there, not knowing the specification, I've wrapped my confusion and put that into another inline view `n`... not that this is what we want to do, but just to illustrate (again) an inline view returning a resultset. Whatever value(s) we're trying to get from the - INTERVAL 9 HOUR subquery, I think we can return those as a set as well.

---

With all that said, we can now get around to answering the question that was asked: adding a "calculated table".

If we don't require up to the second results, but can work with cached statistics, I would be looking at materializing the resultset from inline view `a` into a table, and then re-writing the query above to replace the inline view `a` with a reference to the cache table.

```
CREATE TABLE calc_stats_n_days
( codigowine <datatype> PRIMARY KEY
, avg_30_day  DOUBLE
, max_30_day  DOUBLE      
, min_30_day  DOUBLE
, avg_15_day  DOUBLE
, ...
```

For the initial population...

```
INSERT INTO calc_stats_n_days 
( codigowine, avg_30_day, maxg_30_day, min_30_day, avg_15_day, ... )
         SELECT h.codigowine
              , AVG(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS avg_30_day
              , MAX(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS max_30_day
              , MIN(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -30 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS min_30_day
              , AVG(IF( h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -15 DAY, h.preconormal, NULL)) AS avg_15_day 
              , ...
```

For ongoing sync, I'd probably create a temporary table, populate it with the same query, and then do a sync between the temporary table and the target table. Maybe an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` and `DELETE` anti-join (to remove old rows).

Comment: Thank you for that whole class! I accepted O. Jones's answer as it was more effective and was the first one. I really appreciate your whole effort though! The reasons for the - INTERVAL 9 HOUR is because the job kicks in at 9AM, so I thought it would make sense to pick up yesterday's date as part of the average/mode while the job didn't run, otherwise with only - INTERVAL 7 DAYS I though I was going to be picking up only 6 records after midnight.

Comment: The answer from O.Jones uses the same essential approach: using aggregation to retrieve a set, rather than using correlated subqueries. (CTE support added in MySQL 8.0 and Maria 10.something, it's not available in earlier versions; benefits of CTE is that it can be referenced more than once, and it relocates the view query out of the body of the outer query.) I recommend we qualify *all* column references, my preference is to use short table alias. And note we can use *conditional aggregation* in a single query to get resuls for s7, s15, s30, rather than three separate queries.

Answer (score 2):

Before considering other options, try and make the query more efficient. This is beneficial on the long term: even if you eventually move to a calculated table, you will still take advantage of a more efficient refresh query.

Your query has 15-20 inline subqueries that all address the same dependant table (as far as I read) and do aggregate computations for the same column `precos(preconormal)` (min, max, avg, most occuring value). Each metric is computed several times in a date range that varies from 9 hours back to 1 month back. So it goes:

```
SELECT 
    codigowine, 
    nomevinho, 
    DATE(timestamp) AS data_adc,
    -- ...

    /* Medidas estatísticas para 7 dias - min, max, media e moda  */
    ROUND(
        (
            SELECT MIN(preconormal)
            FROM precos
            WHERE 
                codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
                AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        ), 
        2
    ) AS min_7_dias,
    ROUND(
        (
            SELECT MAX(preconormal)
            FROM precos
            WHERE 
                codigowine = vinhos.codigowine
                AND timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        ), 
        2
    ) AS max_7_dias,

    -- ... and so on ...

FROM vinhos
```

It seems like it could be more efficient to do all computation at once, using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    codigowine,
    min(preconormal) min_30d 
    max(preconormal) max_30d,
    avg(preconormal) avg_30d,
    min(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day) min_15d,
    max(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day) max_15d,
    avg(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day) avg_15d,
    min(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day) min_07d,
    max(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day) max_07d,
    avg(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day) avg_07d
from precos
where timestamp >= current_date - interval 30 day
group by codigowine
```

For performance, you want an index on `(codigowine, timestamp, preconormal)`.

Then you can join it with the original table:

```
select
    v.nomevinho, 
    date(v.timestamp) data_adc,
    p.*
from vinhos v
inner join (
    select 
        codigowine,
        min(preconormal) min_30d 
        max(preconormal) max_30d,
        avg(preconormal) avg_30d,
        min(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then preconormal end) min_15d,
        max(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then preconormal end) max_15d,
        avg(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then preconormal end) avg_15d,
        min(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then preconormal end) min_07d,
        max(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then preconormal end) max_07d,
        avg(case when timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then preconormal end) avg_07d
    from precos
    where timestamp >= current_date - interval 30 day
    group by codigowine         
) p on p.codigowine = v.codigowine
```

This should be a sensible base query to build upon. To get the other computed values (most occuring value per period, latest value), you may add additional joins, or use inline queries.

To finish: here is another version of the base query, that aggregates *after* the join. Depending on how your data spreads across the two tables, this may, or may not be more efficient (and will not be equivalent if there are duplicates `codigowine` in table `vinhos`):

```
select
    v.nomevinho, 
    date(v.timestamp) data_adc,
    p.codigowine,
    date(v.timestamp) data_adc,
    min(p.preconormal) min_30d 
    max(p.preconormal) max_30d,
    avg(p.preconormal) avg_30d,
    min(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then p.preconormal end) min_15d,
    max(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then p.preconormal end) max_15d,
    avg(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 15 day then p.preconormal end) avg_15d,
    min(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then p.preconormal end) min_07d,
    max(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then p.preconormal end) max_07d,
    avg(case when p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 7  day then p.preconormal end) avg_07d
from vinhos v
inner join precos p
    on  p.codigowine = v.codigowine
    and p.timestamp >= current_date - interval 30 day
group by v.codigowine, v.nomevinho
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative and a different approach! I learned more by reading your (and others) answers than I did in a couple of semesters in class. I accepted O. Jones's answer as it was more effective and was the first one.

Comment: Welcome @LucasNeto! Glad that you feel this was useful to you.